I'm having a problem with my microphone, my voice is it like a alien
I'm having a problem with my microphone, where my voice is looking like a alien voice. I hope someone could help me with that. And, in the windows 11 my audio is normal(I did dual boot)

Which ubuntu version? Can you share more information about your hardware?

which alien? ...

the problem cannot be with the microphone ... you said that the audio is normal in Win11
